# Unable to use the styles at page level in UWP

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have created a ResourcesDictionary for styles file and I have one `MainPage.xaml`. When I'm using styles from resource dictionary in mainpage.xaml it threw an error as "resource can't be solved". Could you please tell me the answer how to use styles in page level not application level.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my sample code:

```
<views:MvxWindowsPage
    x:Class="Sample.UWP.Views.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Model="using:Sample.Core.ViewModels"
    xmlns:local="using:Sample.UWP"
    xmlns:views="using:MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ig="using:Infragistics.Controls"
    xmlns:entities="using:Sample.Core.Business.Entities"
    mc:Ignorable="d" IsTabStop="False" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries Source="SampleStyle.xaml">
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="None" ImageSource="Resources\activation_port_bg.png" AlignmentY="Top" AlignmentX="Center"/>
        </Grid.Background>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="50,75,50,75" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox  BorderBrush="LightGray" x:Name="txt1" PlaceholderText="id" Background="White" Width="300"
                      Text="{Binding id, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="50,175,50,75" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Background="#FF30DABB" x:Name="btnSignin" Content="signin" Command="{Binding SigninCommand}" Width="300">
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="50,240,50,75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource stackStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <!--<Image x:Name="image" Height="100" Source="/Resources/activation_port_bg.png"/>-->
            <!--<Button Content="Button Style" Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}"/>-->
            <Button Content="Button Style" Style="{StaticResource btnStyle}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border Style="{StaticResource brdr}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</views:MvxWindowsPage>
```

and My SampleStyle.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TimeCard.UWP.Common">

    <!--sample test styles-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="sampleStyle">
        <Style TargetType="TextBox"/>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <!--Border styles-->
    <Style x:Key="brdr" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="2,2,8,8"/>
    </Style>

    <!--Button styles-->
    <Style x:Key="btnStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25" />
                    <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
                    <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Styles/SampleStyle1.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Styles/SampleStyle2.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Styles/SampleStyle3.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```